# R - loop script that pulls data from online database and have unique name for each iteration

Tags: r, for-loop, uniqueidentifier, data-retrieval

I'm fairly new to R and have been struggling with simplifying some code using a for loop. I am attempting to pull water quality data from an online database using the package **dataRetrieval**. I currently have duplicated the code for each site and changed the site number and output name, but have been trying to simplify this by putting the script in a **for loop** and am having trouble with creating the separate data tables with unique identifiers.

Original Code that creates a data table for each site. The only variables that changes are the `siteNumbers` and the data table name "x"`_dataTable`

```
#BW00A
siteNumbers = c("383652091125002")
parameterCode = c("00010","00095", "00300", "00400", "34475", "34485", "45617")
startDate = "1900-01-01"
endDate = "2020-12-01"

BW00A_dataTable <- readNWISqw(siteNumbers, parameterCode,
                             startDate, endDate)
#BW01
siteNumbers = c("383648091124501")
parameterCode = c("00010","00095", "00300", "00400", "34475", "34485", "45617")
startDate = "1900-01-01"
endDate = "2020-12-01"

BW01_dataTable <- readNWISqw(siteNumbers, parameterCode,
                             startDate, endDate)
#BW01A
siteNumbers = c("383648091124502")
parameterCode = c("00010","00095", "00300", "00400", "34475", "34485", "45617")
startDate = "1900-01-01"
endDate = "2020-12-01"

BW01A_dataTable <- readNWISqw(siteNumbers, parameterCode,
                             startDate, endDate)
```

New Code I can't get to work. I've placed the `siteNumbers` and `siteNames` into a data frame. What I want is for the script inside the **for loop** to iterate through the `siteNumbers` to pull the data and then attribute the newly created data table to the corresponding `siteNames` aka `unique_siteName`. I'm not sure if this is even possible.

```
df <- data.frame(
  siteNumbers = c("383652091125001",    "383652091125002",  "383648091124501",  "383648091124502",  "383506091132201",  "383508091132002",  "383508091132004",  "383519091133701",  "383544091132601",  "383544091132502",  "383628091124801",  "383639091125902",  "383639091125901",  "383638091125001",  "383638091125002",  "383631091124803",  "383631091124804",  "383631091124801",  "383631091124802",  "383636091123801",  "383636091123811",  "383616091125701",  "383640091130701",  "383640091130702",  "383621091130701",  "383621091130703",  "383621091130702",  "383624091130501",  "383624091130502",  "383616091130801",  "383616091130802",  "383644091131601",  "383627091130201",  "383622091130604",  "383622091130605",  "383557091132001",  "383614091132801"),
  siteName = c("BW-00", "BW-00A",   "BW-01",    "BW-01A",   "MW-04",    "MW-04A",   "MW-04B",   "MW-11",    "BW-21",    "BW-21A",   "210TB-C6", "Bates Spring", "Bates Spring below dam",   "BW-02",    "BW-02A",   "BW-04A-D", "BW-04A-S", "BW-04D",   "BW-04S",   "BW-05",    "BW-05A",   "BW-07",    "BW-08",    "BW-08A",   "BW-11",    "BW-11A-D", "BW-11A-S", "BW-13",    "BW-13A",   "BW-14",    "BW-14A",   "BW4-15",   "BW4-16",   "BW4-17",   "BW4-18",   "W3",   "W4")
)

parameterCode = c("00010","00095", "00300", "00400", "34475", "34485", "45617")
startDate = "1900-01-01"
endDate = "2020-12-01"

for (row in df)
{
 unique_siteName <- readNWISqw(siteNumbers, parameterCode,
                             startDate, endDate)  
  
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In R it is generally a best practice to save related objects like dataframes in a list.  You can assign names to each list object and/or reference the list object by its numerical index.  E.g., `mylist[[3]]` refers to the 3rd object in the list `mylist`.  Processing all related objects in a list is also facilitated with the lapply function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the row index and reference the data frame with row number in the loop, and create a `list` to accumulate the results:

```
results <- list()
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
 results[[i]] <- readNWISqw(df$siteNumbers[i], parameterCode,
                             startDate, endDate)  
}
names(results) <- df$siteName
```

R also offers `lapply` as a way to simplify this common pattern. The above loop is equivalent to this:

```
results <- lapply(df$siteNumbers, FUN = readNWISqs, parameterCode, startDate, endDate)
names(results) <- df$siteName
```

I'd suggest reading my answer at [How to make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) for more discussion and explanation, both for why we do it this way and what good next steps are (for example, combining the `results` list into a single data frame).